# Javascript works fine but very slowly in IE, why?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, performance

Excuse my ignorance for I'm a rookie programmer and my language mistakes for I'm a non native english speaker.

I've got a page that, on some click events triggers some javascript and loads ,via php, content into an iframe which also performs some javascript actions (on itself and on the parent page). Everything works fine on FF and all the features work fine in IE too. But the performance in IE is terribly slow...one of the main features is to change opacity of some pictures on mouse up, and it takes 2s+ for IE to display the new opacity. Why? and more important, what can I do to fix it?

Thanks in advance,
Irene

Comment: Its a known fact that the JavaScript Engine in IE is not the fastest.  You could try optimizing your code.

Comment: What version of IE? Do you have a sample page we could test?

Comment: This made me laugh out loud!  This is a good question, Arha, just very funny :)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know...I don't have a test page right now, but I'll post it if necessary, I'll try optimization first...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE has a horribly slow JavaScript engine compared to every other major browser (I'm speaking to IE8 not IE9+)...that's just how it is.  You may want to disable certain things in IE, and of course optimize your script overall.

You may for example want to disable the fade in IE, or give it far fewer frames (longer interval in-between steps), because of its DirectX opacity filter, it's much slower than other browsers in *most* fade situations.

To profile performance problems specific to IE, I highly recommend [dynaTrace AJAX edition](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fajax.dynatrace.com%2F&ei=vMfrTODIIsH-8Abev9Ba&usg=AFQjCNEnfQEtQarv_IVNXxh55-ZViyPxZw), it's a free performance profiler made just for IE.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks! maybe I can ignore some of the opacity changes although all I have in the page in kinda necessary...I have a draggable div and dragging performs awfully slow...but I need it...

Comment: @Arha - check out the profile of your page, it could be something really easy to optimize, or changing things to bind via `.live()`/`.delegate()` in other cases, so the initialization cost is much lower.

Answer (score 1):

Benchmarks showing how slow things can be in IE: http://www.favbrowser.com/chrome-vs-opera-vs-firefox-vs-internet-explorer-vs-safari/

You might need to experiment with different ways of manipulating the DOM to increase the performance in IE.

Comment: Newer versions of IE (> 9) are now a lot better at javascript performance.  Though this does not help people using older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

IE is known to be a bit slow (sarcasm). I don't know exactly what you are doing, but maybe you might want to remove some effects if the user is using IE? Maybe you are doing a lot of DOM changes.

It would be handy to see the code in order to give you tips on how to get a better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here you go, this is probably the script that's creating most of the problems...any suggestions?

```
$(function() {

$("#myTable").draggable({
    containment:'parent',
    drag:function() {
        $("#myTable").css("opacity", "0.6");
        $("#myTable").css("background-image", 'none');
        $("#galframe").css("opacity", "1.0");

    },
    stop:function(){
        $("#myTable").css("opacity", "1.0");
        $("#galframe").css("opacity", "0.6");
        var $image = $("#galframe").contents().find("#jgal div.active img");
                var src=$image[0].src;
                $("#myTable").css("background-image", 'url(' + src + ')');
                $position = $("#myTable").position();
                $("#myTable").css("backgroundPosition", (-parseInt($position.left)+549).toString()+ "px " + (-parseInt($position.top)+20).toString() + "px");
                $("#myTable").css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
            }
});
});
```

Comment: Next time, update your original question with the example and use formatting.

Comment: You are using the wrong event: change drag to start. The drag function will be fired everytime you move the mouse which makes everything slow. The start function will only be fired once.

Comment: That's incredibly helpful...thank you so much. I just tried it, works much better, still slow, but better.